# Is there a command to list the users which user or root has created?

Tags: terminal

Is there a command where which I can input into terminal to list the users which have been created by a user or root? I don't want to use the GUI interface I'm wondering if there is a command.

Comment: `cat /etc/passwd` ? `awk -F: '{print $5}' /etc/passwd` ?   `awk -F: '$3 > 99 {print $5}' /etc/passwd` ? all unix user are either created when host is installed, or by root.

Comment: use `getent passwd` rather than `cat /etc/passwd` because (depending on /etc/nsswitch.conf and/or PAM configuration) unix user account details may be somewhere else entirely - ldap, winbind, mysql, pgsql, nis, an nss extrausers file, nss db, and many more.  ditto for `getent group` vs `cat /etc/group`.